# Build package with custom gcc location

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile

I trying to build c++ package with gcc4.9 through Makefile.
By default system always uses System Compiler (/usr/bin/g++), which is gcc4.5. To use 4.9 i have added it as dependncy of my package.

To use custom location of GCC i have set below command in Makefile

```
override CXX := $(shell  {some path})/gcc-rhel5/bin/g++
override CC := $(shell  {some-path})/gcc-rhel5/bin/g++
```

After this package is building with above mentioned g++ path but i am getting below exception.

**/cc1plus: error while loading shared libraries: libmpc.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

How can i fix this issue.

Comment: Can you call *that* `g++` from the shell?

Comment: With shell i am getting only custom gcc location

Comment: I meant whether you can run that `g++` without problems outside the makefile.

Comment: I think i should be, actually all the things are running on remote machine.

Comment: I'm not sure but you may need to add the location of `libmpc.so.3` to the  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` enviroment variable.

Comment: Building and using a custom version of gcc is possible, but is not easy. You managed to install it, however the build binaries' load library paths are incorrect, so you have to fiddle with the environment variables every time you run it, as the answer below indicates. It takes quite a bit of work to build a custom version of gcc that's installed in a non-default location, and with all shared library load paths correctly set. This is not easy.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming** you have the complete build tools with your custom version of **gcc**. just execute your make command like this. **Please do remove the lines that you added to your makefile**. You should not hard code compiler paths.

```
$ cd yourproject/
$ PATH={some path}/gcc-rhel5/bin LD_LIBRARY_PATH={some path}/gcc-rhel5/lib make
```

**Note**: You need the complete build tools with your compiler to do this and also the shared libraries which corresponds to your custom version of gcc. i.e You cannot just copy only the bin files , You should have a directory structure something like this....

```
-gcc-rhel5/
--bin/
---gcc
---g++
---make
---ld
--lib/
---libmpc.so.3
---libc.so.6
--(some other files)
```